# Solve the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{2a\cosh^2(x/a)} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I have tried to solve this integral. The solution is the following
$$\frac{1}{2a} \bigg[ ax\tanh\Big[\frac{x}{a}\Big]-a^2\log\bigg(\cosh\Big[\frac{x}{a}\Big]\bigg)\bigg]
$$

It should be evaluated from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. It seems that the solution diverges because of the first term. But Wolfram Mathematica shows that the solution is $\frac{a}{2}\log(2)$. Is there a way to find such a solution. I have tried to expand into Taylor series but it doesn't help

Comment: The integral in the title is zero because it is an integrable odd function over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: If you really want to utilize the antiderivative that you found, note that $$\frac{x}{2}\tanh\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)=|x|\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{e^{2|x|/a}+1}\right)$$ and $$\frac{a}{2}\log\cosh\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)=\frac{|x|}{2}+\frac{a}{2}\log\left(\frac{1+e^{-2|x|/a}}{2}\right).$$ This tells that $$\frac{x}{2}\tanh\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)-\frac{a}{2}\log\cosh\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)=-\frac{|x|}{e^{2|x|/a}+1}+\frac{a}{2}\log\left(\frac{2}{1+e^{-2|x|/a}}\right),$$ and this converges to $\frac{a}{2}\log2$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ as Mathematica shows.